# Python socket does not connect on two machines

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

I recently learnt `socket` library in python. I'm coding a game's multiplayer server but before coding the whole multiplayer server I decided to code a small server just for seeing how a server works in python. When I coded the server it was awkward that my code was working fine when I ran the client and server on my own windows 10 computer , it connected and did it's work(it's work is two get the `IP` from `hostname`, but the client will send hostname and the code for getting `IP` is executed in the server and sent back to the client) but when I shared the client file with my friend then the client and server did not connect, there was no error message or something else, firewall is not blocking any connections, so why aren't they connecting? Here's the code in the server file(The `print` statements are just for making a loading bar effect):

```
import socket
from time import sleep
#Default port number: 1234
server=socket.socket()
def run_server(port=1234):
    print('Booting server...')
    print('|-|-|-',end='')
    sleep(0.05)
    server.bind(('',port))
    print('|-|-|-',end='')
    sleep(0.05)
    server.listen(5)
    print('|-|-|',end='')
    sleep(0.05)
    print('\nServer is running and can be accessed now\n===============================================')
    while True:
        c,addr=server.accept()
        print('recieved connection from: ',addr)
        c.send(bytes("ip=bytes(input('Welcome. Enter hostname to extract ip from: '),'utf-8')",'utf-8'))
        c.send(bytes('_socket.send(ip)','utf-8'))
        reply=c.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        try:
            ip=socket.gethostbyname(reply)
        except:
           c.send(bytes('''print("The hostname is either invalid or wasn't found")''','utf-8'))
           c.send(bytes('_socket.close()','utf-8'))
           continue
        c.send(bytes("print('"+ip+"')",'utf-8'))
        c.send(bytes('_socket.close()','utf-8'))
run_server()
```

And the code in the client:

```
import socket
def run(mode='client'):
    _socket=socket.socket()
##    if mode=='client':
    _socket.connect(('192.168.0.101',1234))
##        return True
    while True:
        command=_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        exec(command)
##    if mode=='server':
##        _socket.bind((socket.gethostname(),1234))
##        _socket.listen(5)
##        while True:
##            client,addr=_socket.accept()
##            msg=client.recv(1024)
##            if msg[-1]!=b'.':
##                continue
##            else:
##                _socket.close()
##                break
##        return pickle.loads(msg)
while True:
    try:
        run()
    except OSError:
        continue
```

(ignore the commented code, I just kept it so I can copy it in other files when needed)

NOTE: Whenever I connect these sockets, they connect and then raise an `OSError` saying that an operation was performed on something that's not a socket, when I cover up the error using `try` and `except` blocks nothing really makes a difference, the error is hidden and the server and client work fine(on my own computer only), here's the error:

```
[WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

Comment: you probably havent port forwarded

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean..

Comment: read this https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-port-forwarding-2483494, it explains what it is and how to do it at the bottom

Comment: OK but how to apply that to my code

Comment: 2 things, first, are you giving your public IP to your friend to connect with? second, if you are there doesnt appear to be anything wrong with your code however you need to port forward still for it to work

Comment: I gave my IPv4 address and I still did not understand how to port forward in python using code

Comment: is that your **public** IPv4 address? and if you look at what i sent you then you'd see port forwarding isnt python specific but instead a setting on your router that allows incoming connections and routes them to the right device

Comment: yes its public one @Evorage